# Defining an abstract method in a SQLAlchemy base class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

From http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/improve_toc/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html#augmenting-the-base I see that you can define methods and attributes in the base class.

I'd like to make sure that all the child classes implement a particular method. However, in trying to define an abstract method like so:

```
import abc
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

class Base(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def implement_me(self):
        pass

Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
```

I get the error `TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases`

I tried to find some documentation or examples to help me but came up short.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like you can pass a metaclass to [`declarative_base`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base).  The default metaclass is `DeclarativeMeta` -- So, I think the key would be to create a new metaclass that is a mixin of `abc.ABCMeta` and `DeclarativeMeta`:

```
import abc
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, DeclarativeMeta

class DeclarativeABCMeta(DeclarativeMeta, abc.ABCMeta):
    pass

class Base(declarative_base(metaclass=DeclarativeABCMeta)):
    __abstract__ = True
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def implement_me(self):
        """Canhaz override?"""
```

<sup>*Untested</sup>

Comment: This appears to be working so far with one minor addition: I had to set `__abstract__ = True` in `Base`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This was a life saver. Thank you